# Change first select record

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript code to populate a second select box based on the choice of the first one, but I'm having some troubles making it work correctly.

If I have at least 2 select values, on change event it fires the next select box correctly, but if I have only one option since the change event isn't possible, how I can make it fire the next select box with the loaded value?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
$("#category").change(function(){
var selectedCategory = $("#category option:selected").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "subcategories.php",
    data: { category : selectedCategory } 
}).done(function(data){
    $("#subcategory").html(data);
});
});

});
</script>
```

Basically if my code have at least 2 options, it works:

```
<select name="category" class="form-control" id="category">
<option value="1">Category 1</option>
<option value="2">Category 2</option>
</select>
```

Otherwhise if it have only one option it doesn't work since I can't fire the change event:

```
<select name="category" class="form-control" id="category">
<option value="1">Category 1</option>
</select>
```

I want to make it work without using a "dummy Select Option like " "Select..." in the select box. What could be the best way to achieve it. I'm taking hours to get it right.

Comment: Could you just set the 2nd to the 1st on initial page load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you are not changing event if only one option in select tag. make a function and call just after loading document and also in change event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("#category").change(function(){ 
            getSubCat();//get sub category after change event
        });
        getSubCat();//get sub category after page load
        function getSubCat(){
            var selectedCategory = $("#category option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "subcategories.php",
                data: { category : selectedCategory } 
            }).done(function(data){
                $("#subcategory").html(data);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this code and still only works when change in select box.

Comment: @Tiago : Sorry I put code in wrong place check now .

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution but don't know if its the best way. Waiting for your concerns about this options.

Basically I doubled the code.
One with the change event, and another just with the selected option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

var selectedCategory = $("#category option:selected").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "subcategories.php",
    data: { category : selectedCategory } 
}).done(function(data){
    $("#subcategory").html(data);
});

$("#category").change(function(){
var selectedCategory = $("#category option:selected").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "subcategories.php",
    data: { category : selectedCategory } 
}).done(function(data){
    $("#subcategory").html(data);
});
});

});
</script>
```

Is this the proper way to do it, or I should change something?